# Unable to customize Stackoverflow by CSS in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I would like to control which parts in Stackoverflow are visible to me by a css file.
There are about ten css -files in Firefox installation folder. I am not sure whether I should edit them or not.

**How can I customize Stackoverflow by CSS in Firefox?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a file called "userContent.css" in your profile folder and it will be loaded on each page. Here's more information: http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html

If you need to make changes which only affect one particular site instead of every site, then you can use this syntax:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
    body {
        background-color:#f0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: [here is my Mozilla profile located](http://www.gemal.dk/mozilla/profile.html)

Answer (score 2):

The CSS equivalent of GreaseMonkey is the [Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) which allows you to overwrite site CSS without modifying your `userChrome.css` file.

With [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) installed, you can simply create a custom user style for stackoverflow containing your css overwrites without risking messing up `userChrome.css`. You can also disable or enable that particular stylesheet at any time. Also, make sure to use `!important` in your style declaration as CSS specificity comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug from http://getfirebug.com

You can also use greasemonkey to do further customization.

Comment: I use firebug, but I have not managed to save my edits permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a very handy addon in Firefox, called GreaseMonkey.  It executes a custom javascript after a page loads, and is able to modify the html on the client side.  For example people use it to strip out various elements, change color, fonts, rearrange elements etc

There is also a book about it [available online for free](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/toc/)

You can get the Greasemonkey add-in [here](http://greasemonkey.mozdev.org/).

Comment: The reason why I have not used GreaseMonkey is that I have had an idea that I can do the same also with CSS. Could you give some examples about areas in which GreaseMonkey is superior to editing CSS only?